# Android get xml from html

Tags: android, html, xml

I want to parse HTML content in my app.
I want to use HtmlCleaner to do that.

I understood that HtmlCleaner convert html to xml.
I'm familiar with parsing xml so I want to do that.

I have this line:

tagNode = new HtmlCleaner(props).clean(new URL(
                    "http://somewebsite.com"));

I get tagNode content.
Is there a way to see XML content that HtmlCleaner returned?
Writing it file or something, so I can property write XML parser.

Tnx.

Comment: whats your data exactly? Any example data pls

Comment: Its some web site with tv program content. Doesn't really matter, I want to see XML content, is there a way to do that??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write it to a file. This is from [HtmlCleaner Java use](http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/javause.php):

```
final CleanerProperties props = new CleanerProperties();
final SimpleHtmlSerializer htmlSerializer = new SimpleHtmlSerializer(props);

htmlSerializer.writeToFile(tagNode, fileName, "utf-8");
```

You may need to catch an IOException that `writeToFile()` might throw.

Comment: I used PrettyXmlSerializer instead! HtmlSerializer trowed some parse errors! But tnx!